# How to self reference Astro component

Tags: astrojs

I have this component Astro component (located at "src/components/Menu.astro");

```
---
export interface MenuItem {
  name: string;
  link: string;
  items?: MenuItem[];
}

export interface Props {
  items: MenuItem[];
  depth: number;
}

const { items, depth } = Astro.props;
---

<ul data-depth={depth}>
  {
    items.map(({ name, link, items: subItems }) => {
      if (subItems && subItems.length > 0) {
        return (
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              {link ? <a href={link}>{name}</a> : <button>{name}</button>}

              <Menu items={subItems} depth={depth + 1} />
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      }

      return (
        <li>
          <a href={link}>{name}</a>
        </li>
      );
    })
  }
</ul>
```

On line 28 (where the line reads `<Menu items={subItems} depth={depth + 1} />`) an error thrown saying;

> ReferenceError: Menu is not defined

How can I self reference an Astro component in this case? Thanks in advance.

PS: "Menu" is the component file's name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Astro has a built in method for this called `Astro.self` that you can use
[Astro.self](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astroself)

Example from docs:

```
---
const { items } = Astro.props;
---
<ul class="nested-list">
  {items.map((item) => (
    <li>
      <!-- If there is a nested data-structure we render `<Astro.self>` -->
      <!-- and can pass props through with the recursive call -->
      {Array.isArray(item) ? (
        <Astro.self items={item} />
      ) : (
        item
      )}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also for the link and the code snippet 

Answer (score 1):

In the front-matter, i.e. between the two `---`, you write `import Menu from "./Menu.astro"`.

You'll get new errors, as you can't use statements in the body.

Change

```
items.map(({ name, link, items: subItems }) => {
      if (subItems && subItems.length > 0) {
        return (
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              {link ? <a href={link}>{name}</a> : <button>{name}</button>}

              <Menu items={subItems} depth={depth + 1} />
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      }

      return (
        <li>
          <a href={link}>{name}</a>
        </li>
      );
    })
```

to

```
items.map(({ name, link, items: subItems }) => 
      (subItems && subItems.length > 0)
        ? <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              {link ? <a href={link}>{name}</a> : <button>{name}</button>}

              <Menu items={subItems} depth={depth + 1} />
            </div>
          </li>

       : <li>
          <a href={link}>{name}</a>
        </li>
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. As a matter of fact I didn't get any errors after adding the import statement to the front-matter and using it in the page as a component. So `import Menu from "./Menu.astro"` in the front-matter did the trick.